# Can't load certain websites, but everything else works

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, website, ping

As of this morning, I suddenly can't reach certain sites at all, but all other sites load fine. The sites that don't load are major sites like CNN.com, ATT.com, etc., so they're certainly not legitimately down all at once.

Some sites, like ATT.com, don't even respond to a `ping`:

```
PING att.com (144.160.36.42): 56 data bytes

--- att.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

Other sites, like NYTimes.com, will eventually load but after a very long delay (multiple minutes), and with a number of missing images/stylesheets. Most other sites I visit all load perfectly fine.

This happens across all three computers on my home network. But it's apparently *not* a DNS issue because I've tried a different DNS on each machine (my default AT&T U-verse DNS, OpenDNS, and Google's DNS) and they all fail on the same sites.

I've restarted my router (Motorola NVG589) twice and it made no difference.

I ran my router's diagnostics and all six tests passed (Ethernet, DSL, PTM, Authentication, IP, DNS). OS X's network diagnostics also report that everything is working correctly.

Is there anything else I can try/check before I resort to calling AT&T tech support?

Comment: This sounds like a problem on AT&T end of things.  You have verified its not on your end, and while you have tried other DNS providers, if AT&T is unable to navigate through a path it does not matter what provider you use.  One way...Connect to a VPN..that will prove its a AT&T problem.

Comment: Apparently the solution was to post this question ;-) Immediately after I posted this, everything started working again...I'd still like to know what the cause was, though.

Comment: Ask that owl from that one candy commericial. He likely know the answer.  I am trying to be funny.  In other words the reason likely was a major node AT&T uses was likely down.